# How to change link with broken link?

Tags: posts, links

I removed all posts in my website. And then, I posted them again. But links is changed.

Example: Original:

> http://mywebsite.com/helloeverybody

After changing:

> http://mywebsite.com/hieverybody

And when I access http://mywebsite.com/helloeverybody, it show "nothing found". Should I do ? I cannot redirect 301 manually because I have a lot of posts. Please help me Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is another way to do this than adding 301 redirects manually.

You removed old posts and then changed URLs of new posts. So there is no way to tell what new post to show, when you enter old URL. You have to manually tell that post "hieverybody" is new version of "helloeverybody"...